# Boolean Cutting a Thread into an Inside Wall

Tags: modeling

My problem is similar to [my boolean modifier isn't cutting into my shape properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130266/my-boolean-modifier-isnt-cutting-into-my-shape-correctly). I am trying to insert an M3 thread into the inside wall of a cylinder. I have part A an M3 bolt from the Bolt Factory, and part B a solidified Cylinder. I think that I need a difference operation. I think that I need Part B as the target to have the Modifier, and part A the bit providing the modification required.

If I juxtapose part A and B, and have the bolt as the target, I correctly lose the bottom threads of the bolt.

But if I try to operate on the cylinder B, nothing happens.

The answer to the similar question involved a prior Mirror Modifier but this does not seem to be necessary or if so why?

I am an 80-year old git, and really struggling! I can supply my shapes, but it is pretty basic in the scheme of things.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file - thx

Comment: I suspect this may be a case of the normals on the inside surface of the cylinder facing the wrong way. Please share your current blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your file.

Comment: I used Robin's example below to help. My default set-up did not display red and blue faces. I still have the problem, wonder now if I need to reorder the modifiers, such that the cylinder is still an unfilled mesh, and the bolt a mesh, make the boolean difference and then solidify the resultant.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers, I'm sure, will help with your Boolean. But there's no need for a Boolean, here. If you can avoid them, (which is quite often,) do avoid them:

[image]

Make part B from a duplicate of part A.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> Set The 3D cursor to selected, in Object Mode, and use it as your Transform Pivot
- Cut off the bottom of your bolt (<kbd>V</kbd> at the first straight circumference, progressively selected)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> flip its faces
- Maybe make a bit of a countersink under linear proportional editing (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>)
- Further extrude your top surface outward (<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>..)
- Extrude downward, <kbd>F</kbd> Fill the hole at the bottom, <kbd>I</kbd> Inset the bottom face...

Then your topology will be good, the match will be exact, (you may want tolerance, but that's another question,) everything will automatically be centered... etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed response and suggestion to avoid the boolean approach. I really appreciate the trouble you have gone to. I think